# Read/Write JSON on server on a Next.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, rest, next.js

this is the first time I am asking questions on stackoverflow.

I am working on small projects which build a 10 pages website with next.js, I have experience implementing CRUD between next.js and firebase. This time, I want to put all the static content of website inside some .json files because the content is not that much.

I successfully get the data in .json file by importing the json file, let the page render them.

When I try to build an api in next.js, I did get GET, POST, PUT, DELETE through postman. But I get stuck when I try to write / modify the content in the json file.

that's what I have try:

`src/app/api/content/route.ts:`

```
import {  GetStaticContent, UpdateProgressBarContent } from "@/app/lib/dataDriver";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: Request, res: Response) {

try{
const data = GetStaticContent();
return NextResponse.json({message:"GET OK", data}, { status: 200 });
} catch (error) {
return NextResponse.json({ message: "error", error }, { status: 500 });
}
}

export async function PUT(req: Request, res: Response) {
const input = await req.json();
try{
UpdateProgressBarContent(input);
return NextResponse.json({message:"PUT OK", input}, { status: 200 });
} catch (error) {
return NextResponse.json({ message: "error", error }, { status: 500 });
}
}
```

```
src/lib/dataDriver.js:
```

```
import pageData from '@/app/\_json/testing.json';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const dataFilePath = path.join(process.cwd(), '../app/_json/individual.json');
console.log(dataFilePath);

let jsonData = require(dataFilePath);

export function GetStaticContent() {
return pageData.staticContent;
}

export function GetProgressBarContent() {
return pageData.progressBarContent;
}

export function UpdateProgressBarContent({input}) {

    const data = fs.readFileSync(jsonData);
    console.log(data);
    
    console.log(input);
    console.log(input.dataName);
    console.log(input.newValue);
    
    fs.writeFileSync(dataFilePath, JSON.stringify(input, null, 4));
    console.log('Data updated');
    console.log(data);

}
```

There is an error of :

```
`Error: Cannot find module '/Users/[myUserName]/Documents/[myProjectName]/src/app/_json/testing.json'`
```

But when I copy that path, and run it in the browser, it works and the json content are showing.

Could you please guide me how to make this works?
or Should I placed those JSON on the server first, and then use a url to get it done?
or What I am doing, is it wrong from the start, I must use a database for this?